# Fourier Transform of continuous time limit mimicking Kronecker Delta

Tags: fourier-transform, kronecker-delta

I understand that Kronecker Delta is a function that is defined for discrete arguments as follows:

$$\delta_{ij} = 
\begin{cases}
0,  & i \ne j \\ 
1, & i = j
\end{cases}$$

However, I want to define a continuous function that as a limit behaves like Kronecker Delta. So I start with a Unit Triangle function
$$T(x) = 
\begin{cases}
1-|x|,  & |x| \lt 1 \\ 
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Then I define this continuous function as a limit like:
$$G(x) = \lim\limits_{k \to \infty} (T(x))^k$$

I want to take continuous time Fourier Transform of $G(x)$. I am able to do that for specific small values of $k$, but the expression keeps growing and I am unable to simplify. Need help with hopefully finding a simple closed form of this FT, as k approaches infinity.

Comment: I think you are looking for the [Dirac's Delta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function) (which is not a function, by the way, but a distribution).

Comment: Hi @Joako. No I don't want dirac delta, as that approaches infinity at $0$. Both $G(x)$ and Kronecker Delta are $1$ at origin.

Comment: @Srini The Kronecker delta is a function of $i$ and $j$, not a function of one real variable. There is no way your function $G$ can approximate this symbol.

Comment: And $G(x)$ approaches 0 at other points away from origin. Kronecker Delta exactly equals 0 other than at origin, but only at integers (and not defined for real x). So forgetting if this G(x) truly mimics Kronecker delta or not, I am interested in any FT closed forms

Comment: Maybe specify a little more which characteristics from the Kronecker Delta you want to have in your continuous case, since as example, the Sifting Property of the discrete case your are only going to have it in the continuous case through the Dirac's delta function. Otherwise there is a plenty of function that can tend to 1, like $\lim_{k \to 0} e^{-x^2/k}$, and the Fourier transform of gaussian function is wide known is also gaussian.

Comment: Sorry, I am unclear about my goals. This is a step I encountered  in a much wider problem I am trying to solve (not yet ready to discuss that in detail). Thanks for your suggestion of using a Gaussian limit. Let me go back and see if that fits my bigger problem.